# About the proof of De Giorgi Theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, holder-spaces, elliptic-equations

here we discuss homogeneous equations with no lower-order terms.

$Lu \equiv -D_{j}(a_{ij}(x)D_{j}u)$in $B_{1}(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$

where  $a_{ij} \in L^{\infty}(B_{1})$ satisfies

$\lambda |\xi|^{2} \leq a_{ij}(x)\xi_{i} \xi_{j}\leq \Lambda |\xi|^{2}$ for all $x \in B_{1}(0)$ e $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

for some positive constants $\lambda$ and $\Lambda$.

Remark : $B_{1}$ is a unit ball centered in $0$.

Done this. I would like to help in the following theorem

*Theorem - Suppose $Lu = 0$ weakly in $B_{1}$. Then there holds*

$\sup\limits_{B_{1/2}}|u(x)|  + \sup\limits_{x,y \in B_{1/2}} \frac{ |u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} \leq c(n,\frac{\Lambda}{\lambda})||u||_{L^{2}(B_{1})}
$

*with $\alpha=\alpha(n,\frac{\Lambda}{\lambda}) \in (0,1)$*

My work: In particular, $u$ is a weakly subsolution then by local boundedness theorem (Elliptic partial differential equation- QING HAN / FANGHUA LIN -chapter 4 -pg 67) is valid

$\sup\limits_{B_{1/2}}|u(x)|\leq c(n,\frac{\Lambda}{\lambda})||u||_{L^{2}(B_{1})}$

Now, I believe that, I should to use the oscillation theorem ([about oscillation theorem pg.80](https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/u/0/s/?view=att&th=1513485d04fc7a3e&attid=0.1&disp=attd&realattid=f_ihbzi6hm0&safe=1&zw&saddbat=ANGjdJ9rZd5VIZYpXONattJaxSU9Y9d5zoH0blfhcj1EJnQNRuw2O0lN3LjedtoImzc2QRry3Ha27Xfk56Q5BJJLgfe6h-FZShtn-_WB9hy03BPwmXHzQH10MZkxleAYBB_8cEOROKKYj-UZn4i8xvDlkkrAnuhlyvhscvOrYTQLSN3FNRw6AhCfJBGzuwMEU-VLGIklci4h7NcDXH68AZe2r4EujXPNQcmXmfS_9ulTVOopoH9NZhhDay2MtOq2nSfCy4wPMluzHrfXR_xzawxFWJ9qQoSYUf0DvU_KdU-aIGYrRi9nWonM5vKkrAjrxJomcOBxgolMO6Ax4syLLYYXVzVz66JflVwy25TkQN9y2K_vn8j997cgWHanXbjS64zdpeqGD9aXTtCJTbbDPaKoeZHCSJidf8zIWr5aAZ5EhHh6ziHspTSdcssnMXTPQC_ww6hONsHv3Z83fc3wXkzzCIk30PO-Y6hCREVqHDKTK133juCRoROZEk89H0--kVvwCSmYTqq5-GocGzkKjEk38Z2v3QJkdFhYFLlXIzF_qE0DMif2tTpqy97JnCHk62EjXRlz6HYKsS_g5NikZz_UFZSDXwzMpN-PVWoj0NhGvNrDf-09k0GUr8j0dGrOTaUZ-ePReWkwbZ7OrChE)) but i don't know

Thanks